# React Drag & Drop Effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop

How can I implement a drag-and-drop feature in React for reordering elements in a list? I have a list of items that I want to be able to reorder by dragging and dropping them to a new position. I also want to be able to save the new order in my database. How can I achieve this using React and any necessary libraries?